# Error: Error trying to ping. Error: 2 UNKNOWN

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have updated composer [cli,playground,rest server etc..] from v.0.16.5 to v 0.19.0. After deploying the network when I try to ping the network it first throws an error and then connects to it on the second try. Why is this happening? How can I activate the current identity admin as in error?

```
composer network ping -c admin@university
```

Error: Error trying to ping. Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode: transaction returned with failure: Error: The current identity, with the name 'admin' and the identifier '01899e04161a3a6d64670504fa122e55818295352929b6a616333a3739fde3f2', must be activated (ACTIVATION_REQUIRED)
Command failed

```
composer network ping -c admin@university
```

The connection to the network was successfully tested: university
    Business network version: 0.0.1
    Composer runtime version: 0.19.0
    participant: org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#admin
    identity: org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity#76edd946537645ea0016455a076e32dd10daac1e39fb75200d737b78dbca675d

Command succeeded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an Identity is first used it has an Enrollment ID and Secret, and a status of "ISSUED".  After the first use the Secret is invalidated and Certificates are passed to the client Wallet and the ID has a status of "ACTIVATED".

You can see these different states in this example output from `composer identity list` command:

```
$class:      org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity
  identityId:  3a1f3c629ef2106b138836f3c9e5fe1ac8358c60a4a1232c5ef1a16a805ab313
  name:        mary
  issuer:      ac3dbcbe135ba48b29f97665bb103f8260c38d3872473e584314392797c595f3
  certificate: 
  state:       ISSUED
  participant: resource:org.acme.mynetwork.Trader#mary


- 
  $class:      org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity
  identityId:  57d1f173c6a9a7f789d243749de16340fee8bf383748d47ac360f846e5c238b9
  name:        mark
  issuer:      ac3dbcbe135ba48b29f97665bb103f8260c38d3872473e584314392797c595f3
  certificate: 
    """
  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  MIICbTCCAhOgAwIBAgIUWHvLyD+Vs6YE1KTpCm1LlQej728wCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIw
  czELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExFjAUBgNVBAcTDVNh
  biBGcmFuY2lzY28xGTAXBgNVBAoTEG9yZzEuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20xHDAaBgNVBAMT
  E2NhLm9yZzEuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20wHhcNMTgwNDAzMTExNjAwWhcNMTkwNDAzMTEy
  MTAwWjAtMRwwDQYDVQQLEwZjbGllbnQwCwYDVQQLEwRvcmcxMQ0wCwYDVQQDEwRt
  YXJrMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAER3WsqouV+M07SG8gMExLFCZs
  8aUSsH8hMRUhKjibzV8fE/JJMOitoLSRpa/KU24p9IiDqBPZY/QdszTE5wzbuqOB
  yjCBxzAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCB4AwDAYDVR0TAQH/BAIwADAdBgNVHQ4EFgQU7EL5
  azn+RHinsX6EvEFZeQ5/II4wKwYDVR0jBCQwIoAgGatlq7sEgH2tEuTAqaqmZJ5w
  ho46vQIXoyLYnkfhpq4wWwYIKgMEBQYHCAEET3siYXR0cnMiOnsiaGYuQWZmaWxp
  YXRpb24iOiJvcmcxIiwiaGYuRW5yb2xsbWVudElEIjoibWFyayIsImhmLlR5cGUi
  OiJjbGllbnQifX0wCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIDSAAwRQIhAJSXtjEMu/8xkd0uLzJOP91h
  JdHa57ihiPkxOjRGqthTAiAMFrhY0gu/yUxN9cuLdmt/tNaile8W2/Kt+yZBW+ng
  gg==
  -----END CERTIFICATE-----

    """
  state:       ACTIVATED
  participant: resource:org.acme.mynetwork.Trader#t01
```

The `composer identity list` command gives a server side view, but a client side view can be seen with `composer card list` :

```
composer card list -c mary
userName:            mary
description:         
businessNetworkName: tutorial-network
identityId:          
roles:               none
connectionProfile: 
  name:   hlfv1
  x-type: hlfv1
credentials:         One time use only secret set

composer card list -c mark@tutorial-network
userName:            mark
description:         
businessNetworkName: tutorial-network
identityId:          57d1f173c6a9a7f789d243749de16340fee8bf383748d47ac360f846e5c238b9
roles:               none
connectionProfile: 
  name:   hlfv1
  x-type: hlfv1
credentials:         Credentials set
```

So your transition from 'Activation Required' to activitated is OK, but what is unusual is the "command failed" - what is normal is that the transition from ISSUED to ACTIVATED is hidden from the user, and the first ping works!

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the response.What should I do for the first ping to work?

Comment: Is this repeatable for you - does it happen for each new network, or for each new user for the network?  If it is repeatable you could turn on debugging on the client side, and you could look at the logs of the containers (CA and Peer) at the time of the error.